# Issues validating HTML when using variables in URL

Tags: php, w3c-validation

I am getting this error when running my page through the W3C validator:

= in an unquoted attribute value. Probable causes: Attributes running together or a URL query string in an unquoted attribute value.

Here is the code that is causing this error:

```
$prevPage = "?main=men&amp;category1=1&amp;pagenum=$prevp"."&amp;lowRowNum=$prev_page_low".
                    "&amp;highRowNum=$prev_page_high";

print("<a class='left' href=$prevPage>".
                    "Previous Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

I am not getting any error like this in any of my other PHP scripts , so I am guessing it is something specific I am doing wrong here?

Can anyone see why this code is causing this error?

I have researched this and read that it may be down to HTML special characters? I am not sure..

Thank you

Comment: You are trying to validate HTML. Show us HTML, not PHP.

Comment: The HTML in question was the href anchor in my post, this was the HTML that was causing the issue, I have received an answer which solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Why is my question being down voted? Its a perfectly valid question!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply try:

```
<a class='left' href='$prevPage'>
```

Notice the quotes. Always try to quote your attributes in HTML. Better practice would be to:

```
echo '<a class="left" href="' . $prevPage . '">' //etc etc;
```

Try not to echo the entire HTML string as you might get confused when using single vs. double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem, it would have taken me a century to notice that! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a combination of [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf) and [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) here:

```php
printf(
  '<a class="left" href="%s">Previous Page</a>'
    , htmlentities($prevPage)
);
```

`printf()` takes a string and `echo`s it after replacing specially-formatted tokens.  In the above example, there is one token in the string, represented as `%s`.

When `printf()` runs, it replaces each token with a corresponding parameter.  In the above example, the `%s` is replaced by the result of `htmlentities($prevPage)`.

[The manual page for `sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) goes into more detail about how the tokens work and has many more examples (`sprintf()` and `printf()` are identical except that `sprintf()` returns the formatted string, while `printf()` outputs it directly).

To ensure that entities such as `&` are encoded correctly for markup validation, you should also make use of `htmlentities()`.

Comment: That's excellent, I read about this when researching my problem, I never understood it, but I like your suggestion, thanks for explaining that for me!!